# get number of weeks away from today

Tags: c#, date

i have a date in the future and i want to find out how many weeks away this is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(futureDate - DateTime.Today).TotalDays / 7
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be best getting the no of days and dividing that by 7

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
DateTime end = DateTime.Now.AddDays(21);

double noOfDays = (end - start).TotalDays;
double noOfWeeks = noOfDays  / 7;
```